# $\min$-entropy for the uniform distribution on $[]$

Tags: analysis, statistics, machine-learning, entropy

The min-entropy of a distribution $\nu$ on $[n]$ is given as:
$$H_{\infty}(\nu)=\min_{i} \log(\frac{1}{\nu(i)})$$

Now we will prove that that for every distribution $\nu$ on $[n]$  and for $U$ being the uniform distribution on $[n]$, then we have that:
$$H_{\infty}(\nu) \leq H_{\infty}(U)$$
My thought us that the distribution of $U$ is $\frac{1}{n}$, then we get that $\log(\frac{1}{(\frac{1}{n})_i})=(n)_i$, has minimum in the first element so $H_{\infty}(U)=1?$ But the lowest element must be 1 because $i\geq 1$, therefore $H_{\infty}(\nu) \leq H_{\infty}(U)$?
I'm not sure if I have understood it correct? Something says me that is not correct, but I don't think I understand what the i means. Can anyone help me?

Comment: How are you defining $H_\infty (\nu)$? Because you should get $H_\infty(U) = \log(n),$ and not one.

Comment: So the min-entropy is the same as the entropy for discrete uniform distribution on  $[]$? Why?

Comment: Please do not delete your question immediately after getting an answer.  This is disrespectful to the person who took the time to answer your question, and to future readers who might find the Q&A helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing $[n] = [1,n] \cap \mathbf{N}.$ Also $H_\infty(U) = \log n$ and $\nu$ is discrete. If $\nu$ is discrete, and it is different from the uniform distribution, then $\nu(i) > \frac{1}{n}$ for some $i,$ as the opposite assumption will yield $\nu([n]) < 1.$ (To see this, observe that if $\nu(i) \leq \frac{1}{n}$ for all $i,$ and $\nu$ is not the uniform distribution, then $\nu(i_0) < \frac{1}{n}$ for some $i_0,$ and then $\nu([n]) = \sum_i \nu(i) = \nu(i_0) + \sum_{i \neq i_0} \nu(i) < \frac{1}{n} + \frac{n-1}{n} = 1,$ contradicting the fact $\nu$ is a probability mass function.) Then $H_\infty(\nu) < \log(n).$

Comment: So the min-entropy is the same as the entropy for discrete uniform distribution on  $[]$? Why?

Comment: No, I proved that the entropy of a discrete distribution $\nu$ satisfies $H_\infty(nu) \leq H_\infty(U) = \log(n),$ and that the equality will happen if and only if $\nu$ is the uniform distribution.

Comment: @Lifeni Min-entropy is the same as entropy for the uniform distribution on $[n]$ because $\min\{\log n, \log n, \ldots, \log n\}$ is the same as $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n} \log n$, i.e. "the minimum of a set of numbers is the same as the its average, if all numbers in the set are equal."

Comment: Aha now I understand. Thank you